# How to initialize an array of structs in C

Tags: c, struct

I can not see why my code doesn't work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct date{
    int month, day, year;
} Date;

typedef struct person{
    char name[32];
    Date date;
}Person;

int main()
{
    Person presidents[4];
    presidents[0] = {"George Washington", {30, 4, 1789}};
    presidents[1] = {"Thomas Jefferson", {4, 3, 1801}};
    presidents[2] = {"Abraham Lincoln", {4, 3, 1861}};
    presidents[3] = {"Theodore Roosevelt", {14, 8, 1901}};

    return 0;
}
```

This is the compiler's output:

```
>||=== Build: Debug in MyProject (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
>C:\Users\My pc\OneDrive\Documents\c\MyProject\main.c||In function 'main':|
>C:\Users\My pc\OneDrive\Documents\c\MyProject\main.c|16|error: expected expression before '{' token|
>C:\Users\My pc\OneDrive\Documents\c\MyProject\main.c|17|error: expected expression before '{' token|
>C:\Users\My pc\OneDrive\Documents\c\MyProject\main.c|18|error: expected expression before '{' token|
>C:\Users\My pc\OneDrive\Documents\c\MyProject\main.c|19|error: expected expression before '{' token|
>C:\Users\My pc\OneDrive\Documents\c\MyProject\main.c|15|warning: variable 'presidents' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]|
>||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Person presidents[] = {
    {"George Washington", {30, 4, 1789}},
    {"Thomas Jefferson", {4, 3, 1801}},
    {"Abraham Lincoln", {4, 3, 1861}},
    {"Theodore Roosevelt", {14, 8, 1901}}
};
```

The initialization is always in the form

```
type var = init_val;
```

and the code above shows how to initalize an array of structs. Please note how you don't need to specify the number of elements of the `presidents` array, as the compiler will obtain it from the number of elements in the initializer.

Comment: @BUG you can, using compound literals (as suggested by DavidRanieri), but it would be technically a set of assignments and not an initialization. You cannot do as you did... because the C syntax forbids it.

Answer (score 2):

As an extension to @RobertoCaboni's answer, since C99 you can also use [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal):

```
Person presidents[4];
presidents[0] = (Person){"George Washington", {30, 4, 1789}};
presidents[1] = (Person){"Thomas Jefferson", {4, 3, 1801}};
presidents[2] = (Person){"Abraham Lincoln", {4, 3, 1861}};
presidents[3] = (Person){"Theodore Roosevelt", {14, 8, 1901}};
```

Comment: +1, though it is technically an assignment rather than an initialization. But it is correct as I guess OP meant asking about the assignment in general.